flutter run aint giving the expected results even when you save and re run
why does the default code for the incrementor keep running yet  i changed the code base,, am literally seeing the incrementor app being run yet i have made my custom work , even when you do flutter clean, pub get it still persists, iam confused its actually ambiguous
iexpected to see my app running but instead the incrementor comes again

Please verify your main.dart file. The execution starts from main.dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Check whether your main.dart file is updated and the runApp is pointing to your custom code.
